# Keras Import - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'error'

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I already installed a keras but when i run a code in python3 there is an error.

**Following is a code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

from skimage.transform import resize

from keras import backend as K
```

**and the error says:**

```
Using TensorFlow backend.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

File "C:\Users\AzUm\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-env\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module> from . import utils

File "C:\Users\AzUm\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-env\lib\site packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 25, in <module> from .training_utils import multi_gpu_model

File "C:\Users\AzUm\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-env\lib\site packages\keras\utils\training_utils.py", line 1, in <module> from ..layers.merge import concatenate

File "C:\Users\AzUm\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-env\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 4, in <module> from ..engine import Layer

File "C:\Users\AzUm\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\__init__.py", line 3, in <module> from .topology import InputSpec

File "C:\Users\AzUm\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 8, in <module> import yaml

File "C:\Users\AzUm\Anaconda3\envs\opencv-env\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 2, in <module> from error import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'error'
```

Comment: Please include the error message!

Comment: The problem is with the YAML package that is a dependency of Keras. It looks like similar to this problem: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/112

Answer (score 0):

To solve the above problem you can use this link https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml

If setup.py is not found then give the path where setup.py is placed like this

C:\Users\AzUm\Downloads\pyyaml-master>python setup.py install